# Геометрическая сумма графиков в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, графика

Пытаюсь получить суперпозицию графиков, но по точкам считать как-то неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как из нескольких графиков нормально получить их сумму?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

kvant = [1.2, 8.9, 7.8, -2.4, -8.9, 4.2, 1.2, 8.9, 1.2, -5.4, 1.2]


x = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
sum = []
for i in range (0, len(kvant)):
       y = kvant[i]*np.sin(x-i)/(x-i)
       sum.append(y)
       plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1.0)
plt.plot(sum, y, linewidth=1.0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `по точкам считать как-то неправильно.` если имеется в виду - по исходным данным, то это как раз правильный путь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*как из нескольких графиков нормально получить их сумму*  --->

Ну, например, вот так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

kvant = [1.2, 8.9, 7.8, -2.4, -8.9, 4.2, 1.2, 8.9, 1.2, -5.4, 1.2]
x = np.linspace(0, 12, 100)
sum = np.zeros(len(x))
for i in range (0, len(kvant)):
       y = kvant[i]*np.sin(x-i)/(x-i)
       sum=sum+y
       plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1.0)
plt.plot(x,sum, linewidth=5.0)
```

Результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Попытался так сделать изначально, но перепутал x и y местами и подумал, что не вышло)